# Trouble Decrypting Responses from ACS ACR1255U-J1 NFC Reader After Successful Authentication

Tags: bluetooth, cryptography, nfc

I'm working on implementing a communication module for the ACS ACR1255U-J1 NFC Reader device within my web application. I've successfully completed the authentication step as described in the [documentation](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/7664/REF-ACR1255U-J1-1.13.pdf) (pages 33-37).

However, I'm encountering difficulties when trying to decrypt responses from data blocks. It appears that the decrypted responses do not contain meaningful data, and I suspect that I might be using the incorrect key for decryption.

To understand what's happening, I downloaded their demo Android app, which can be found here: [ACS-BLE-EVK-Android-0.53.zip](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-driver-unified/13088/ACS-BLE-EVK-Android-0.53.zip). I also enabled Bluetooth HCI snoop logging on my Android device.

After installing their demo app, I opened it, connected to the scanner, authenticated myself, enabled polling, and scanned an NFC tag a few times. Following that, I transferred the Bluetooth logs to my PC to observe captured Bluetooth traffic using Wireshark.

Fortunately, I was able to identify a set of packets that are clearly used for authentication purposes:

The first command in the series is sent to the reader and requests the ACR1255U-J1 to perform authentication (**SPH_to_RDR_ReqAuth**):

```
05 00 0c 6b 00 05 00 00 00 cb e0 00 00 45 00 0c 0a
```

After the **SPH_to_RDR_ReqAuth**, the NFC Scanner responds with **RDR_to_SPH_AuthRsp1**:

```
05 00 1c 83 00 15 00 00 02 64 e1 00 00 45 00 [5c 04 db 7f cd ef 62 98 44 45 89 2f c2 00 03 16] 1c 0a
```

The data in the square brackets represents a 16-byte random number generated by the reader, which needs to be encrypted with the default master key (the default value is: 41435231323535552d4a312041757468).
This encrypted value will be used in the next step of authentication.

Additionally, I used my own decryption function and obtained the decrypted value:

```
02 54 00 bf 03 90 43 8c 33 85 17 83 cc e1 16 08.
```

The next step involves sending the ***SPH_to_RDR_AuthRsp*** command, which is the second phase of the authentication process. The actual data sent from the demo app is:

```
05 00 2c 6b 00 25 00 01 00 ff e0 00 00 46 00 [db 66 c9 a2 7a 8f 6b 00 b0 d8 36 6c 8a 10 89 73 c2 69 09 9a 71 78 96 27 85 d8 4c 07 6b f5 19 1d] 2c 0a
```

According to the documentation, the data in the square brackets is a 32-byte decrypted data block. The first 16 bytes are the random number generated by the client, and the second 16-byte section represents data generated by the NFC Reader, which should be identical to the data I decrypted in the previous step:

```
02 54 00 bf 03 90 43 8c 33 85 17 83 cc e1 16 08.
```

To confirm this, I encrypted the 32-byte data block in the square brackets with the default master key and obtained the following result:

```
[33 45 b3 12 b2 4d 3c dd b8 1e 1a c5 29 ec 10 24] [02 54 00 bf 03 90 43 8c 33 85 17 83 cc e1 16 08]
```

The first portion represents the data generated by the demo app, and the second represents the 16-byte key.

After **SPH_to_RDR_AuthRsp** the NFC reader responds with **RDR_to_SPH_AuthRsp2** indicating a successful authentication process:

```
05 00 1c 83 00 15 00 01 02 98 e1 00 00 46 00 [2b a7 c3 a5 44 4b 21 7b a0 68 07 0c 20 f7 fc fd] 1c 0a
```

The data in the square brackets represents the encrypted 16-byte data block generated by the demo app. Decrypting it should yield the following value:

```
33 45 b3 12 b2 4d 3c dd b8 1e 1a c5 29 ec 10 24
```

Fortunately, I successfully decrypted it with the master key using my own decryption function.

According to the documentation, every packet after the authentication step contains an encrypted data block. Therefore, I attempted to inspect a few packets.

Let's examine this packet sent from the demo app to the NFC reader:

```
05 00 10 [1d 6b 50 02 bf 78 4a 45 bf 35 30 df 42 3c a4 77] 34 0a
```

When attempting to decrypt the data block in the brackets using my decryption function and the master key, I obtained the following result:

```
76 e8 92 f4 fb 75 ee 0d af 0c 2d 66 97 52 23 b0
```

However, I couldn't find a message in the documentation that matched this result.

Let's consider another packet sent from the NFC reader to the demo app:

```
05 00 10 [9b 07 d8 3c a7 c5 b1 09 71 2c 1f 01 e4 9c 0e 31] b6 0a
```

Again, when attempting to decrypt the data block in the brackets, I couldn't find a message that aligned with the result:

```
0f 73 cc 72 37 1e 3c de c0 c3 73 b9 92 d5 cc 9c
```

My suspicion is that I might not be using the correct key to decrypt the data. The documentation mentions session keys, which are the random numbers generated in the demo app (33 45 b3 12 b2 4d 3c dd b8 1e 1a c5 29 ec 10 24) and by the NFC reader (02 54 00 bf 03 90 43 8c 33 85 17 83 cc e1 16 08) during the authentication process. Despite trying to use these keys for decrypting data packets, I couldn't obtain meaningful results.

For reference, here are my encryption and decryption methods written in JavaScript:

```js
const encrypt = (valueStringHex, hexKey) => {
  const value = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(valueStringHex);
  const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hexKey);
  const ivvar = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("00000000000000000000000000000000");
  const encryptedStringHex = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {
    iv: ivvar,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
  }).ciphertext.toString();
  return encryptedStringHex;
};

const decrypt = (valueStringHex, hexKey) => {
  const value = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(valueStringHex);
  const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hexKey);
  const ivvar = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("00000000000000000000000000000000");
  const decryptedStringHex = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext: value }),
    key,
    { iv: ivvar, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding }
  );
  return decryptedStringHex.toString();
};
```

So my question here is is there anyone that has any expirience working with these type of devices or/and has any idea what's the problem here?

Comment: I've found the answer. Post-authentication, all packets are encrypted. The encryption key is formed by combining keys from RDR_SPH_AuthRsp1 and RDR_to_SPH_AuthRsp1. To create the session key for encryption and decryption, merge the first 8 bytes of the 16-byte server key from RDR_SPH_AuthRsp1 with the first 8 bytes of the client-generated 16-byte key. The correct 16-byte session key for the example above is:


02 54 00 bf 03 90 43 8c 33 45 b3 12 b2 4d 3c dd